# angular app with two almost identical directives - one directive works one doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app with two directives that are almost identical to each other.  One displays perfectly fine.  The other doesn't display at all.  I get no javascript errors in my browser.

Here is distilled code below.  The `time-series-chart` directive works fine.  The `data-box` directive doesn't do anything.

Pulling my hair out - don't know what I'm missing here.

plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/qYXWS7TXrKUS2y1grxTp?p=preview

**edit**:   Jan's answer is right.   `data-` is reserved in angular.  In the plunker, I renamed it to `value-box` and that fixed it right up.

```
   <div>
      <time-series-chart key="keyForChartABC"></time-series-chart>
      <hr>
      <time-series-chart key="keyForChartXYZ"></time-series-chart>
      <hr> 
      <!-- this one is broken ! -->
      <data-box key="keyForDataBox"></data-box>
  </div>
```

script

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ChartController', 'DataBoxController'])
  .controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.keyForChartABC = "somekey1";
      $scope.keyForChartXYZ = "somekey2";
      $scope.keyForDataBox = "dbkey";
    }
  ])
   // this one is broken
   .directive('dataBox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            key: '='
        },
        templateUrl : 'databox.html',
        controller: 'DataBoxController',
        controllerAs: 'dbctrl',
        bindToController: true
    }
})
   // this one works fine
  .directive('timeSeriesChart', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        key: '='
      },
      templateUrl : 'chartwidget.html',
      controller: 'ChartController',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      bindToController: true
    }
});

  // this one doesn't work
  angular.module('DataBoxController', [])
  .controller('DataBoxController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope){
    $scope.didIGetIt = this.key;
    $scope.lastValue = Math.random() * 1000;

    console.log(this.key);
  });
  // this works
  angular.module('ChartController', [])
  .controller('ChartController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope){
    $scope.didIGetIt = this.key;
    $scope.lastValue = Math.random() * 1000;

    console.log(this.key);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're naming one directive `data-` which is a [reserved name for angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Rename it to something else and it will work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/yHgPTPkS2wCIXtVzMvay?p=preview